# French Door Draft Issue - Top Corner Not Touching Astragal

Tags: doors, sealing, door-frame, new-home, draft

I recently moved into a new home with French doors, and I'm facing an issue with the front door. When the door is latched, the top corner on the strike side doesn't make contact with the astragal, resulting in a significant draft problem.

I've already tried tightening the hinges, but unfortunately, it didn't seem to make any difference. I'm reaching out to seek advice on potential solutions or troubleshooting steps to address this problem.

Any recommendations on how to adjust the door to ensure a proper seal and eliminate the draft? Are there specific tools or techniques I should consider for this type of French door? Your expertise would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.[image: Exterior Gap]

[image: Interior Gap]

[image: Strike]

[image: Gap with Credit Card for Scale]

[image: Bottom seal exterior]

Comment: Seems to me one or both doors is warped.  If you want the door to mate up to the astragal evenly, you need to either unwarp the door (probably difficult) or reset the hinges so the door is slightly crooked at the jamb.  Have you checked the doors' plumbness at the hinge side and astragal side?